# Avoid parallax images hardcoding

Tags: php, theme-development

I like to have the possibility to use the parallax effect in my custom theme. For posts or pages I have a custom shortcode where I can pass the link to the image to use and the text content for it, but I'm unable to find a way to manage this if I want to make use of the parallax for a page like the index or if I want to assign to a custom post type. Is there a good solution to let the user choice what Image to use and on what page?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  What does your shortcode accomplish now?

Comment: the shortcode will display a parallax jumbotron and the attributes will define the image to use and the additional id or class to add to the markup. maybe `do_shortcode` will do the trick?